# VS Code Output Issue

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my code on vs code and every time it runs it seems to return the directory to where my file is located. I'm not sure what caused this as before it would show my code.[image]

Comment: Can you describe in detail how you run this file? For example, whether to use other extensions, and whether the workspace is currently open

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yeah, that's the expected behavior in VS code if you don't want that you can change it to output only instead of running in the terminal.